# FAIL Error: 4011

Tags: paypal

This is my form:

```
<form method=post action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
     <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_notify-synch">
     <input type="hidden" name="tx" value="<?php echo $_GET['tx']; ?>">
     <input type="hidden" name="at" value="52522320223225333633365254541">
     <input type="submit" value="PDT"> 
</form>
```

When i submit the above form the fail will occur.

---

Comment: You tagged the question with php, where is the php code?

Comment: I'm getting similar error. Were you able to find solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

> This error was cause by using SandBox credentials, while redirecting
>   to non-sandbox URL.

[PayPal Express returns 4011 error message in Sandbox mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415640/paypal-express-returns-4011-error-message-in-sandbox-mode)

Comment: here u can see i m posting the form to same url but diffrent params,  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Comment: please check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887028/create-paypal-sandbox-merchant-seller-account)